# In magento 2 How to call phtml file in static block

Tags: magento2, static-block

I have created extension in Magento 2 and i want to call index.phtml file from static block (from admin panel).
Module structure

> Ashore>Faq>Block>Faq>Index.phtml
>
> Ashore>Faq>View>frontend>Templates>faq>index.phtml

how can i call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{{block class="<vendor_name>\<module_name>\Block\<module_name>" name="<your_block_name>" template="<vendor_name>_<module_name>::<template_directory>/filename.phtml"}}
```

In your case it is look like

```
{{block class="Ashore\Faq\Block\Faq\Index" name="Faq" template="Ashore_Faq::faq/index.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Use this to call template file in static block

```
{{block class="Block Name" template="PackageName_ ModuleName::phtml file name"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call your **.phtml** file in **CMS page** like below

```
{{block class="Ashore\Faq\Block\Faq\Index" name="faq" template="Ashore_Faq::faq/index.phtml"}}
```